# Will the name of the class change after the rebuild in the css-modules?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm going to use css-modules in react

Suppose I got an App___Logo____1mzDG31 class
in the css-modules the name of the class will be new all the time after the build?
How to be a tester, what to link to if 1mzDG31 can be changed
or will 1mzDG31 never change?

Comment: The name of the module classes are generated using a hash, so, it will kinda random (well, that's the purpose of the css module)

Answer (score 0):

It will generate a unique name from a hash, not the same name. But while using css modules, you can reference your class the same way you attribute one to your DOM element. Like this example below:

```
import classes from './Style.module.css';
classes.yourclassname
```